# Set up an autogateway

Tags: linux, networking, gateway

I don't do very heavy linux sysadmin, but we are up to ~35 servers that I run. I'm an engineer by trade and just know enough about linux to be able to help when things go wrong. Now that we have a decent amount of servers registered on the company DNS. It is hard to track which computer to use, so that you aren't bombarded by people training models or running some crazy sim on it. We have a dashboard that allows people to view what is most used, but I wanted an automated workflow. Someway I could just say ssh user@my-server-group and it would run through all the computers and check which had the "least usage" by a custom metric and then pass me along to that computer. Is this possible? I figure somebody has already made this. What are some alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're looking for what in high performance computing and compute clusters would be called a cluster aware job/batch scheduler and/or workload manager - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler - Expect quite a learning curve though when you need to implement something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community, but before posting, please read their guidelines. Alternatively Wikipedia often has lists of available products, such as for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cluster_software

Comment: I don't want job submission. I would just like to automatically be able to ssh into the "freest" computer. Job submission seems overkill. I guess I could just create some code on the backend of my dashboard that shows the current "freeest" computer. And maybe even update an environment variable so somebody could ssh user@$FREEEST. Just seems like somebody has to have made what I want for midsized clusters.